# Why did Rey hear both Alec Guinness and Ewan McGregor?

Tags: star-wars, the-force-awakens, the-rise-of-skywalker

It's the only Jedi voice that wavers like that. This happens in:

1. *The Force Awakens*, at the end of the 'forceback': first Guinness, "Rey?" then McGregor "these are your first steps"
2. *The Rise of Skywalker*, first McGregor "these are your final steps", then Guinness "Rey?"

In *The Rise of Skywalker* Guinness appears right after Qui-Gon says "we stand behind you".

Comment: I'm leaning towards this to be an inconsistency they overlooked here. I think she should hear the old Ben Kenobi's voice, because that's his form when he became a Force Ghost.

Answer (score 5):

The moviemakers made a choice to include the voice of the original actor in the film as not only a tribute to Alec Guiness, but as a sign of welcome to the older fans of the original movies. That's what you might suppose.
The reason was - because it was technically possible:

> Amazing what they can do these days. But! They found a, they got a
> line of him as Alec...Obi-Wan Kenobi saying "afraid" and they just cut
> the "a" and the "d" off and they got that "Rey" and then they used
> that. So Alec Guinness is saying "Rey" and then I say "these are your
> first steps."

Any romanticist notion of why it might have been done is unsupported by any evidence that I could find.

Answer (score 1):

Force Ghosts appear to be outside of time to some degree. Some appear similar to how they looked right before death, while at least one looked much younger.

[image]

Perhaps their voices are also taken from across their life-span.

Additionally, while it is true that his is "the only Jedi voice that wavers like that," other factors are in play. Kenobi is fairly unique in that he has two prominent actors. Most of the other Jedi only have one actor (or if they have two, one is a voice actor doing an impression of the other). The only other exception is Anakin, who has a few prominent actors as well. However, Jones' voice was augmented by technology, making it odd if his ghost spoke with it. I argue Lloyd would not have been wholly out of place, but [he chose to separate himself from the franchise](https://web.archive.org/web/20120312032002/http://entertainment.msnbc.msn.com/_news/2012/03/09/10611651-actor-who-played-anakin-skywalker-as-child-swears-off-star-wars-for-good). Ultimately, my point is that is is possible that the other characters also spoke from across their lifespans, we just didn't notice because there was only one actor portraying them across that lifespan.

Answer (score -2):

You need to remember the difference between actors and characters.

Alec Guinness portrayed Obi-wan Kenobi in Star Wars, The Empire Strikes Back, and Return of the Jedi.

Ewen McGregor portrayed Obi-wan Kenobi in The phantom Menace, Attack of the Clones, and Revenge of the Sith.

Daisy Ridley portrayed Rey in The Force Awakens, the Last Jedi, and The Rise of Skywalker.

So in real life Daisy Ridley has often heard Alec Guinness and Ewen McGregor when watching movies they were in, and possibly heard Ewen McGregor in person sometimes.

And in the fictional universe of the movies, Obi-wan Kenobi had only one body and voice.

If someone pretends that Star Wars is a series of historical films based on records of actual past events which found their way to Earth somehow, obviously the filmakers couldn't possibly find good actors who looked and sounded exactly like the historical characters they portray.  The filmakers might have only a vague idea what the "historical" characters looked and sounded like.

It is not even certain that members of the Star Wars species portrayed by human actors without prosthetics in Star Wars "actually" did look like members of the species *Homo spapiens*. Obi-wan Kenobi might really look more like Greedo or Chewbacca than like a human.

So Rey the fictional character heard only one single voice of Obi-wan Kenobi, and it didn't "really" sound exactly like Alec Guinness or exactly like Ewen McGregor, let alone sound exactly like both at diferent times.

And possibly the moviemakers reused sound clips of Alec Guinness saying words in previous Star Wars films, and combined them together to make Obi-wan Kenobi say lines in the sequal trillogy.  And maybe they then paid Ewen MCGregor to say the lines they wanted Obi-wan Kenobi to speak which they could not assemble from Alec Guinness sound clips that way.

Comment: I don't understand how Daisy Ridley hearing voices of Alec Guinness and Ewan McGregor in real life matters in this scenario.

Comment: @Sandun The title question conflates character and actor names, so it’s not a clear question. I read this answer as trying to untangle the strange wording of the question by talking about the different ways the mixture of character and actor names could be interpreted.

Comment: I think it's clear. It means young(er) and old(er) Obi-Wan. Rey hears both:  OT Obi-Wan and pre-OT Obi-Wan. Obi-Wan was played by two actors. So the character is 'conflated' with two people to begin with. It doesn't seem like an accident. Vader became his younger self as a force ghost.